# google sheets find by row and sum

Tags: google-sheets

This is a simplified version of my data.

[image]

I want to calculate the "Whole Tax" row Automatically. I mean I'm looking for any special google sheets formula that can search for those records that are equal to "TAX" and SUM on the values in corresponding month.

Comment: in addition to using built in functions, if it makes development faster, you can use the `QUERY()` SQL-like database queries, since I see you know quite a bit about php/MySQL.

Comment: 4,991 rep (and now 5,001 rep after i upvoted you) are you really allowed to post an image only and no spreadsheet or code?

Comment: @BCLC I thought images are more permanent that spreadsheet links. But sure next time I will upload spreadsheet link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have posted a spreadsheet instead of an image to find out your locale. Try in B17, assuming TAX is not preceded by white spaces

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$16="TAX",B2:B16)
```

Comment: What if TAX is actually preceded by white spaces?

Comment: Then replace `"TAX"` in the formula by `"    TAX"` with the exact number of spaces

Comment: @Salar not sure if it's possible with `SUMPRODUCT` but see my edit for wildcards in `SUMIF`. That said, `SUMPRODUCT` remains a versatile and powerful tool.

Comment: I used TRIM function for removing extra spaces and it worked well.

Answer (score 2):

In google sheet `QUERY()` function is really faster and more scalable. You can use wildcard character to ignore leading and trailing spaces. Try below formula.

```
=SUM(QUERY($A$3:$D$16,"SELECT B WHERE LOWER(A) LIKE '%tax%'"))
```

On single go get sum of all columns. As per my screenshot put below formula to `B17` cell.

```
=QUERY($A$3:$D$16,"SELECT SUM(B), SUM(C), SUM(D) WHERE LOWER(A) LIKE '%tax%' LABEL SUM(B) '', SUM(C) '', SUM(D) ''")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider placing sums at the top of each column so you can select cells using `A2:A` for rest of column.

Anyhow, use `=SUMIF($A$1:$A$15, "*tax", B1:B15)` for strings that end in tax, case-insensitive. The wildcard selectors are `*` for wildcard strings and `?` for wildcard characters. Use `~` to escape.

Comment: I think I can also use TRIM function on the input range. but I don't know the performance comparison between * character or TRIM function. any idea?

Comment: Good question. TRIM seems to require additional storage since `TRIM($A$1:$A$15)` doesn't work for me.

Comment: its wondering why SUMIF does not work with TRIM but, SUMPRODUCT does.

Comment: @Salar TRIM() function will make your formula slower for large dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Harun24HR, here is a more flexible formula in which you do not have to designate each column

```
=QUERY({A3:D16},"SELECT SUM(Col"&arrayformula(textjoin("),SUM(Col",,COLUMN(B3:D)))&") WHERE LOWER(Col1) LIKE '%tax%' LABEL SUM(Col"&arrayformula(textjoin(")'', SUM(Col",,COLUMN(B3:D)))&") '' ")
```